# Error handler at callsite not catching error

Tags: javascript, axios

In this example, `createSchedule` makes an api request, if the api request fails I'd anticipate to log the message in my catch block since I am not handling the error in `createSchedule`. Here is an abbreviated version of the code:

Call site:

```
Schedule.onCustomEvent('Schedule:created', async function () {
  const schedule = this;
  try {
    return createSchedule(schedule);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Schedule Error: Did not create schedule for ${schedule.name} : ${schedule._id}`);
    console.error(e);
  }
});
```

Definition:

```
const createSchedule = async (schedule) => {
  // headers defined outside of func
  // url defined outside of func

  const { data } = await axios( {
    method: 'post',
    url,
    headers,
    data: {
      schedule: {
        name: schedule.name,        
        timezone: schedule.getTimezone() || 'US/Eastern'
      },
      enable_sis_reactivation: true,
    }
  })
  return data;
}
```

Within `createSchedule` I do not have an error handler. At the call-site, I have an error handler, however the logging in the handler isn't logged.

I tested this with providing bad credentials in the header so the post request would return a 401, this wasn't logged in my error handler at the call-site. In addition, I removed the `url` variable defined above the `createSchedule` function and got a reference error, however the catch block logs were not logged.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are returning the whatever reponse you get, try below code

```
Schedule.onCustomEvent('Schedule:created', async function () {
  const schedule = this;
  try {
    let create = await createSchedule(schedule);
    return create
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Schedule Error: Did not create schedule for ${schedule.name} : ${schedule._id}`);
    console.error(e);
  }
});
```

```
const createSchedule = async (schedule) => {
    // headers defined outside of func
    // url defined outside of func

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const {
                data
            } = await axios({
                method: 'post',
                url,
                headers,
                data: {
                    schedule: {
                        name: schedule.name,
                        timezone: schedule.getTimezone() || 'US/Eastern'
                    },
                    enable_sis_reactivation: true,
                }
            })
            return resolve(data);
        }
        cache(err) {
            return reject(err)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I refactored this. This doesn't work. Overall I believe returning anything from an async function implicitly adds await.

Comment: @HelloWorld if possible to edit createSchedule function you can try the above